# How to overlay/place an image on a video in ffmpeg

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg

Hey guys I am trying to overlay an image at the cntre of a video in ffmpeg like this:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i image.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0,20)'" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output.mp4
```

But the image get placed on the top-left side of the video. How can I adjust the image to the centre?

Answer (score 16):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i image.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:enable='between(t,0,20)'" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output.mp4
```

`W` amd `H` are the base video's dimensions. And `w` and `h` the overlay video's.

Comment: Hey, thanks, @Mulvya. Can you tell me how can I position the image on the video?

Comment: The first two arguments in the overlay are the x and y coordinates with respect to the top left of the Base video.

Comment: How provide a specific time here?
Like I wanted to overlay an image on specific time frame then how to do it?@Mulvya

Comment: It's already there in the answer : `enable='between(t,0,20)`